# Android maps auto zooming

Tags: android

Hi Im having a little issue with displaying points on a map. 
I use an Arraylist to store multiple lat/lng values and then do a for loop to add the point and auto zoom. Everything works fine when there are 2 or more markers. The problem is when only 1 marker is added it zooms in too close.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

```
 public static void processMap()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++)
    {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat.get(i), lng.get(i));

        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("title");
        markerOptions.snippet("description");

        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        bounds.include(new LatLng(lat.get(i), lng.get(i)));
    }

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 150));
}
```

**Updated code**

```
public static void processMap()
    {
        int num = 0;
        double lat2 = 0;
        double lng2 = 0;

        for (int l = 0; l < lat.size(); l++)
        {
            lat2 = lat.get(l);
            lng2 = lng.get(l);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat2, lng2);

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(title.get(l));
            markerOptions.snippet(description.get(l));

            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            bounds.include(new LatLng(lat2, lng2));
            num++;
        }

        if (num == 1)
        {
// if only 1 marker
            LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(lat2, lng2);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng2, 16));
        }
        else
        {
// more than 1 marker
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 150));
        }
    }
```

Hi sorry I didn't reply earlier I was attempting to fix the problem. I managed to fix it, but is this the correct way of going about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit you made should fix your problem. Anyway you don't need to set new LatLng if you only  have 1 marker. Passing the bound should do. I would make this little edit:

```
if (num == 1)
    {
// if only 1 marker
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.build(), 16));
    }
    else
    {
// more than 1 marker
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 150));
    }
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: The method newLatLngZoom(LatLng, float) in the type CameraUpdateFactory is not applicable for the arguments (LatLngBounds, int)  Thats the error I get when I change it to your edit

Comment: Sry forgot to chage `newLatLngZoom` for `newLatLngBounds`. Change that and then put a value for the bounds at your taste. (obviously higher than 150).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not really tell why you are using `.newLatLngBounds()`, but this will center the map on your given bounding box and respecting the given 150px padding around the box.

The zoom is then adapted according to the elements inside the bounding box to show all of them. When there is only one marker inside the box, it will zoom to it (and probably too close). The docs say that the map will be centered "*[at the greatest possible zoom level](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int%29)*".

So to prevent this, I would choose a good zoom level for the first marker, add it, move the camera with `moveCamera(...)` and after that continue with your code when there are other markers left.